# Chain an effect without using the effect's callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I know how to chain two effects so that the second is executed after the first is completed using the callbacks. As so;

```
$("#target").fadeOut('slow',function(){
   $(this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

So this works and the div fades out first before it slides up. I want the slideUp to happen after a successful ajax call, but **after** the fadeOut is finished, but when I do the following code the ajax request happens to quickly and it slidesUp before the fadeOut is finished.

```
$.ajax({
    /** settings **/
    beforeSend: function() {
       $("#target").fadeOut('slow');
    },
    success: function() {
       $("#target").slideUp('slow');
    },
    error: function() {
       $("#target").fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

How can I tell jQuery in the success callback to perform the slideUp after the fadeOut is done.

I did try this.

```
 $("#target").queue(function(){
    $(this).slideUp('slow');
 });
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: whats the problem of using callbacks?

Comment: I need to perform a different animation depending on the success of the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the use of [jquery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
var myDfd = $.Deferred();
$("#target").fadeOut('slow',function(){
   myDfd.resolve();
});

var ajaxDfd = $.ajax({
    /** settings **/
    beforeSend: function() {
       $("#target").fadeOut('slow');
    },
    error: function() {
       $("#target").fadeIn('slow');
    }
});

$.when(ajaxDfd, myDfd).then(function() {
   $("#target").slideUp('slow');
});
```

You wait for the first Deferred (the fadeOut) and the AJAX query are done to execute one single callback.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution !

```
var flag=false;

$.ajax({
    /** settings **/
    beforeSend: function() {
       $("#target").fadeOut('slow', function() {
           flag=true;
       });
    },
    success: function() {
       var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (flag) {
                $("#target").slideUp('slow');
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
       }, 500)
    },
    error: function() {
       $("#target").fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

There's also the complete handler (now called `.done()`), promises, or just `.is(':animated')`, that could be used for this sort of thing. I find that a simple interval usually is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crude way:

```
var done = false;
var todo = null

var amDone = function() {
   if (todo) {
      todo();
   } else {
      done = true;
   }
};

var ifDone = function(f) {
  return function() {
     if (done) {
        f();
     } else {
        todo = f;
     }
  };
};

$.ajax({
    /** settings **/
    beforeSend: function() {
       $("#target").fadeOut('slow', amDone);
    },
    success: ifDone(function() {
       $("#target").slideUp('slow');
    }),
    error: ifDone(function() {
       $("#target").fadeIn('slow');
    })
});
```

**EDIT** fixed to allow different effects